# Inserting a submit button in a switch case

Tags: php

I have a switch case where in each case i have a table. I'm trying to add a submit button just outside the table but i'm failing to do so. I'm not sure if it's applicable or syntactically correct. Any suggestions?

```
    switch ($selected){
        case 'University':
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT employees.actualpost FROM employeesWHERE employees.status='Employed'");
    $stmt->bindParam(':start', $pages->limit_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':end', $pages->limit_end, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $selectedtable = "<table class='sortable'><tr><th>Description</th><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th></tr>\n";
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $selectedtable .= "<tr><th>A</th><td><form method='post' action=''><input type='text' name='Brevet' style=' padding: 10px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></form></td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[3]</td></tr>
                           <tr><th>B</th><td><form method='post' action=''><input type='Baccalaureatbt' name='Brevet' style=' padding: 10px; font-size:16px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></form></td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[3]</td></tr>
                           <tr><th>C</th><td><form method='post' action=''><input type='text' name='Licensets' style=' padding: 10px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></form></td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[3]</td></tr>
                           <tr><th>D</th><td><form method='post' action=''><input type='text' name='M1' style=' padding: 10px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></form></td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[3]</td></tr>
                           <tr><th>E</th><td><form method='post' action=''><input type='text' name='Mastersdegree' style=' padding: 10px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></form></td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[3]</td></tr>
                           <tr><th>F</th><td><form method='post' action=''><input type='text' name='Phd' style=' padding: 10px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></form></td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[3]</td></tr>";

    }

        break;
```

Submit button should be outside the table beneath it: `<form method='post' action=''><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' style='width:80px; height:30px; text-align:center; padding:0px;'></form>`

Comment: @arkascha how do you suggest me doing it? covering the whole table with a form tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see an issue here. Just add it.

Note however that you have to close the table, that is missing in your code above. Also you have to rethink your form construction. There should only be one single form. Not one form for each input. The form should be the outer container that includes all relevant inputs meant to be posted.

```
<?pjp
switch ($selected){
    case 'University':
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT employees.actualpost FROM employeesWHERE employees.status='Employed'");
        $stmt->bindParam(':start', $pages->limit_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':end', $pages->limit_end, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $selectedtable  = "<form method='post' action=''>\n";
        $selectedtable .= "<table class='sortable'>\n<tr><th>Description</th><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th></tr>\n";
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $selectedtable .= "<tr><th>A</th><td><input type='text' name='Brevet' style=' padding: 10px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td></tr>
                       <tr><th>B</th><td><input type='Baccalaureatbt' name='Brevet' style=' padding: 10px; font-size:16px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[3]</td></tr>
                       <tr><th>C</th><td><input type='text' name='Licensets' style=' padding: 10px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td>$row[3]</td></tr>
                       <tr><th>D</th><td><input type='text' name='M1' style=' padding: 10px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td></tr>
                       <tr><th>E</th><td><input type='text' name='Mastersdegree' style=' padding: 10px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td></tr>
                       <tr><th>F</th><td><input type='text' name='Phd' style=' padding: 10px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td></tr>";

    }
    $selectedtable .= "</table>\n"; 
    $selectedtable .= "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' style='width:80px; height:30px; text-align:center; padding:0px;'>\n";
    $selectedtable .= "</form>\n";
    break;
```

*Note however that this style is questionable. It is very hard to maintain. Instead you should think of using the "view" pattern, so store your htm,l markup in a separate file (without using string or echo statements everywhere) and render that by including it in your switch cases. That way your markup gets much more clean (more naturally html like). also you should start using a separate style sheet file you reference to be able to exclude all those inline styles from your table.*

Comment: @dan just one thing, if i'm getting : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$selectedtable'

Comment: on:  $selectedtable .= "<table class='sortable'>\n<tr><th>Description</th><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th></tr>\n";

Comment: what could be the problem

Comment: The code I posted is meant to point out how to do things. It is not meant to be used by copy and paste. You still have to take care of your own code. The issue you mention was simply a missing semicolon (`;`) behind the first assignment to that variable. Sorry for that, but you should easily spot such issues yourself.

Comment: i did not copy/paste, and the problem remains

Comment: Did you add that semicolon? Same issue was in the last but one assignment. No idea how you could run into such error if you did _not_ copy & paste, though :-) I mean nothing against copy&paste. What I meant was just: you still have to understand the code and be able to spot obvious fixes requried.